# Write textbox text to a file while keeping newlines

Tags: c#, text, streamwriter

I have tried using:
StreamWriter.WriteLine()
StreamWriter.Write()
File.WriteAllText()

But all of those methods write the textbox text to the file without keeping newlines and such chars. How can I go about doing this?

EDIT:

```
    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog s = new SaveFileDialog();
        s.FileName = "new_doc.txt";
        s.Filter = "Text File | *.txt";
        if (s.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(s.FileName, richTextBox1.Text);
        }
    }
```

I am using a multiline RichTextBox to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by not keeping newlines?

Comment: @tzortzik The text that gets written is all on one line.

Comment: A piece of code would be better. We should see what you did.

Comment: @tzortzik I added the code I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would help. Is from `StreamWriter` class documentation.

```
string[] str = String.Split(...);

// Write each directory name to a file. 
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("CDriveDirs.txt"))
{
    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in cDirs)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(dir.Name);

    }
}
```

The idea is to get the text from your textbox and then split it after `\n` char. The result will be an array of strings, each element containing one line.

Later edit:

The problem is that return carriage is missing. If you look with debugger at the code, you will see that your string has only `\n` at a new line instead of `\r\n`. If you put this line of code in you function, you will get the results you want:

```
string tbval = richTextBox1.Text;
tbval = tbval.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
```

There should be other solutions for this issue, looking better than this but this one has quick results.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on tzortzik's answer, if you use StreamWriter and simply access the RichTextBox's Lines property, it will do the work for you:

```
    private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog s = new SaveFileDialog();
        s.FileName = "new_doc.txt";
        s.Filter = "Text File | *.txt";
        if (s.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s.FileName))
            {
                foreach (string line in richTextBox1.Lines)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```