# I cant print richTextBox.Text insdie a text file for multiple Lines

Tags: c#

When I try to print the `RichTextBox1.Text` to a Text file, I always get the results in one line even if it was a multiple lines text inside the RichBox.

I want to print the `richBoxText.Text` inside the Text file exactly as its found in the RichBox

```
string[] ReadMeArry = { "<description>", "DE", richTextBox1.Text, "", "EN", richTextBox2.Text, "</description>", "", "<internal>", "Owner: " + textBox3.Text, "Ticket: " + textBox4.Text, "</internal>" };

File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(path, "ReadMe.txt"), ReadMeArry);
```

The text should look like:

```
<description>
DE

"RichBoxText here in mulitple Lines"
.
.
.

EN

</description>

<internal>
Owner: sha
Ticket: s
</internal>
```

Comment: sorry this my first Time and am not sure how to write it to look good

Comment: Chances are that the text is correctly written in multiple lines but that you are looking at it in a text editor that requires Windows linefeeds. Try looking at the file using a more sophisticated editor, e.g. Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code or Notepad++.

Comment: You can try to use `richTextBox.Lines` instead of `richTextBox.Text`

Comment: you are Right, in Notepad its multiple lines, but am still in Need of it to be opended with .txt file and read clearly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write textbox text to a file while keeping newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263609/write-textbox-text-to-a-file-while-keeping-newlines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's because the `WriteAllLines` method can't manage array items which are multilines themselves.

Try to replace this

```
string[] ReadMeArry = { "<description>", "DE", richTextBox1.Text, "", "EN", richTextBox2.Text, "</description>", "", "<internal>", "Owner: " + textBox3.Text, "Ticket: " + textBox4.Text, "</internal>" };
```

with that

```
string[] ReadMeArry = { "<description>", "DE",  "", "EN",  "</description>", "", "<internal>", "Owner: " + textBox3.Text, "Ticket: " + textBox4.Text, "</internal>" };

var res = ReadMeArry
.Concat(richTextBox1.Lines)
.Concat(richTextBox2.Lines).ToArray();

File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(path, "ReadMe.txt"), res);
```

The order is not respected in my exemple, but if this solves your problem it'll be rather simple to tune it to your needs.
It's a quick fix though, given your use case, i think `File.WriteAllLines` might not be the best way to create your file.

Comment: thanks richTextBox1.Lines works, I just didnt know how to use it in my Array